# OAuth2 in ReactNative without third party | login

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on a React Native app and have problems with OAuth2. I don't want to forward to a third-party website, but for the user to enter his username and password. Are there any documentations? I only find resources to third-party forwarding..

I dont have a client-id nor a client-secret.. its just username/password like a normal login flow

I know there's password-grant, but I didn't get it any further or I didn't know how to use it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: same issue on me.. still don´t know how to use OAuth with username/password - i know how to use third party but not first party

Answer (score 1):

You can either use services like [auth0](https://auth0.com/) or [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) to build your own  branded identity provider.

Or if you are feeling curious and ready for some heavy lifting, you can for example use C# .NET with a [Identity Server 4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4), use Go with [go-oauth2](https://github.com/go-oauth2/oauth2), and customize.